# How to grant access to IP range in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, security, network

I would like to configure my Postgres DB to be accessed by any IP 10.8.101.*. I know I have to create a rule in `pg_hba.conf` but I'm not sure what it should look like. My LAN IP is currently 10.8.101.128 so I thought this would work:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             10.8.101.0/128         md5
```

But I'm getting an error `could not load pg_hba.conf`. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The /128 in the address is the NUMBER OF BITS to match...  not a range.

So you would want 10.8.101.0/24 (match the first 24 bits).

As an additional example, if you wanted to restrict it to 10.8.101.128 to 10.8.101.255 then you'd do 10.8.101.128/25

Please see the address subsection in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)